# gltf file is not showing in react nextjs

Tags: reactjs, three.js, next.js, gltf

I am trying to load a gltf file in a nextjs application using threejs.But its not working when i try to run it with nextjs application on react project.This is how i configured  next.js with webpack:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withImages = require('next-images');

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
module.exports = withPlugins([
    [withCSS, { cssModules: true  }],
    [withImages],
], {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {   serverRuntimeConfigValue: 'test server'  },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {   publicRuntimeConfigValue: {apiUrl:process.env.apiUrl.trim()} },
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(glb|gltf)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader',
            }
        })
        return config;   },exportTrailingSlash: true
});
```

I am  importing the file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import GLTFLoader from 'three-gltf-loader';
import  TransformControls  from './TransformControls.js'
import test2 from "../../../static/images/villa.gltf";
```

I wrote this function in componentDidmount to load gltf:

```
   this.loader.load(test2, gltf => {
            this.gltf = gltf.scene

            // ADD MODEL TO THE SCENE
            this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
          

         });
```

This is Network tab when rendering  the gltf file

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to serve assets correctly with `file-loader`, you have to configure with correct location of `_next` static dir as following:

```
{
  loader: 'file-loader',
  options: {
    publicPath: "/_next/static/images", // the path access the assets via url
    outputPath: "static/images/", // where to store on disk
  }
}
```

But looks like you might need to set up to load `.bin` file as well and keep the original name since it will be loaded as the `.load` function is called:

```
webpack: (config) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(glb|gltf)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        publicPath: "/_next/static/images",
        outputPath: "static/images/",
      }
    },
  });
  
  // For bin file
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(bin)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        publicPath: "/_next/static/images",
        outputPath: "static/images/",
        name: '[name].[ext]' // keep the original name
      }
    },
  });
}
```

And also import the `bin` file in your component too:

```js
import "../../../static/images/villa.bin";
```

Comment: thank you.it worked with configuring next static directory.bin file wasn't needed

Comment: If so, your `gltf ` file is unlikely to need the `bin` file